# Why is data that i've sorted in a laravel controller, not displaying as sorted on the view

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have 3 related tables and I want to sort the data by `programme_title` which is in the `programmes` table. This method in my controller works and I can dump the new array sorted by `programme_title`.

However, when I print this in my view (vue.js), the array is sorted by default, `id` again. Any reason for this?

```php
return Inertia::render('Applications/Edit', [
    $programmes = AppProgrammes::with(['programmeInstances', 'programmes'])
        ->get()
        ->sortBy(function($programmes) { 
            return $programmes->programmes->programme_title;
        }),
    'programmes' => $programmes,
]);
```

Comment: Your array looks like it is not correctly formatted... you are returning $programmes as the first element of the array (without index) and then you add `'programmes' => $programmes` (the result of the previous element, like double result).

Comment: @matiaslauriti what do you mean by ''and then you add programmes' => $programmes'? im sending back the sorted array to the view? any ideas how to solve my issue? thanks

Answer (score -1):

This happened once to me, the "issue" is that when you get the final result in javascript, surely it is a JSON, and it is automatically sorted by index (by javascript, that is the unchangeable behavior of Javascript related to JSON), you cannot have a "custom sort"... so you will have to find another solution for this...

I know it is really frustrating, but it is the only way...

If you dump your result, I think I could try to help you more.